# HTML Lists styling issue with Dynamic Content

Tags: css, html-lists

I've had this issue come up a few times and I'm totally lost.

Whenever I create border-bottom lines on ul li items, and if the li item is two lines, it ignores the padding, or eats into the padding.

How do you fix this?

See this line: tech: custom wordpress theme, because it drops on two lines it doesn't space evenly.

[Link] (http://natashamcdiarmid.com/nm_portfolio/3-oaks-landscaping/)

```
ul#portfolio-details li{
   height:100%;
   padding:8px 0 40px 0;
   line-height:1.2em;
   border-bottom:1px #f2f3f4 solid;
}
```

Comment: The list you show on the link doesn't have border-bottom lines, nor does it appear to have any padding issues O.o can you take a screen shot of what you're seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
ul#portfolio-details li{
   height:100%;
   padding:8px 0 20px 0;
   line-height:1.2em;
   border-bottom:1px #f2f3f4 solid;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `li`s are not wrapping around their floated contents. To fix that, add `overflow: hidden`:

```
li {overflow: hidden;}
```

Then you will probably want to reduce the margins/paddings a bit (which were in there for the wrong reasons).

> Note, however, that it's invalid to have a div directly inside a `ul`. You need to have `li`s there instead.